# Xcode crash trying to add an array as 'value' to dictionary (using playground file)

Tags: swift

After many experiments and many crashes, I still can't figure it out:

```
var dictionary:Dictionary<String, Any> = ["A": "Val A"]

var array = ["A", "B"]

dictionary["Ar"] = /* Xcode crash as soon as I type 'a' 
                      and autocomplete brings up my 'array' */
```

I tried many different ways, including adding an empty array, (which partly worked), but as soon as I add something to that array, Xcode blows up.

Apple did mentioned that "*Swift arrays are specific about the kinds of values they can store.*", but that should not conflict. Type 'Any' is still a type. Of course, a compiler **warning** is what one would expect, but then again, this *is* a beta version.

Comment: Probably an Xcode bug. You should post about this on the Apple dev forums.

Comment: I saw that now, happened same thing.

Comment: It is happening in Playground. Already submitted bug report to Apple. It just seemed to me like a big deal, and considering I found no posts about this, I thought I'm missing something.

Comment: The crash only seems to occur when the array is a variable. Xcode doesn't crash for me with `let array = ["A", "B"]`

Comment: This does not seem to be an Xcode bug. I tried the same thing from the Swift REPL and I got a seg fault (after trying to assign the array)

Comment: @ 0x7fffffff Good job! Yes, it works with 'let'. Maybe the array has to be constant?  @ drewag Playground does kind of 'run time' thing, so yea. But still not clear as to the official position about arrays in dictionaty

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the safety of arrays and Dictionaries

This code works:

```
var dictionary:Dictionary<String, Array<String>> = ["A": []]

var array = ["A", "B"]


dictionary["Ar"] = array
```

but this crashes:

```
var dictionary:Dictionary<String, Any> = ["A": []]

var array: String[] = ["A", "B"]


dictionary["Ar"] = array
```

I can confirm the bug is happening for me as well, so I think that rules out the possibility that array's can't be included in dictionaries.

Comment: Yes. The big issue is however, how Swift's Dictionary will replace the 'id'-friendly NSDictionary. Meaning, store an 'Object', String, Integer, instance, etc. in the same instance.